# Allocating Data Structures and passing info into a Data Structure

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures, linked-list, dynamic-memory-allocation

How do I make this program  with no warnings...Keeps saying tail uninitialized for a warning. Trying to make a loop that prints out all my data instead of having to call the function every time with a different parameter. If I set tail = to COP3330, then it doesn't print out the COP3330 info since it's then = to NULL. Thank you!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <malloc.h>

typedef struct UCF_Classes
{
   char *ClassIdentifier, *ClassName, *Department;
   int Credits;
   struct UCF_Classes *next;
}Info;

Info *CreateList(char *ClassNumber, char *NameOfClass, char *DepartmentName, int NumOfCredits)
{
    Info *NewClass;

    NewClass = (Info *) malloc(sizeof(Info));

    NewClass->ClassIdentifier = ClassNumber;
    NewClass->ClassName = NameOfClass;
    NewClass->Department = DepartmentName;
    NewClass->Credits = NumOfCredits;

   return NewClass;
}

void WalkListAndDisplay(Info *walker)
{
   printf("%s\n", walker->ClassIdentifier);
   printf("%s\n", walker->ClassName);
   printf("%s\n", walker->Department);
   printf("%d\n\n", walker->Credits);
}

int main()
{
   Info *COP3223, *COP3502C, *COP3503C, *COP3330, *head, *tail;

   COP3223 = CreateList("COP3223", "Intro to Programming with C", "College of Engineering and Computer Science", 3);
   COP3502C = CreateList("COP3502C", "Computer Science I", "College of Engineering and Computer Science", 3);
   COP3503C = CreateList("COP3503C", "Computer Science II", "College of Engineering and Computer Science", 3);
   COP3330 = CreateList("COP3330", "Object Oriented Programming", "College of Engineering and Computer Science", 3);

   head = COP3223;

   COP3223->next = COP3502C;
   COP3502C->next = COP3503C;
   COP3503C->next = COP3330;
   COP3330->next = tail;
   tail->next = NULL;

   while(head->next != NULL)
   {
       WalkListAndDisplay(head);
       head = head->next;
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have not allocate any memory for `tail` pointer to point, and no initial value, either.   From your code, you don't really need `tail`, you can just make `COP3330->next` points to `NULL`.

Comment: Firstly, does SSC stand for Seminole State College? Second, If I do that it won't print out the last data for COP3330 since my while loop stops once it reaches NULL. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Looks like you should change your while loop to `while(head != NULL)` as well. Having `tail` in your code was hiding a bug.

Comment: YES! Please explain why I didn't need head->next and what the difference is if possible! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `while` loop is not checking the current node for null before trying to print it, it's checking the next node. If you think about the order here, it's like it's saying, "The next node is available, so print the current one." This means that when it gets to the end of the list, it thinks it's done one node early because there is no node after it. It should instead say, "The current node is available, so print it and then step forward."

Your `tail` variable, as SSC pointed out, is not needed, and was actually hiding this bug by making the last node in your list have something besides NULL to point to. This made the flawed while condition true for the last node. Your code would have crashed with an empty list though because `head->next` would have dereferenced a NULL pointer.

Remove `tail`, and change your `while` statement to this:

```
while(head != NULL)
{
    WalkListAndDisplay(head);
    head = head->next;
}
```

Comment: Wonderful! Thank you for the explanation!

Comment: @MikeKoofer Sure thing. By the way, I see your a new user. If this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: I had no idea about the check-mark. Thank you for the information!